# Как получить строку из нескольких повторений слова?

Tags: c#

Есть слово: `string str = "text";`
Как задать 20 повторений этого слова, то есть чтобы слово `"text"` было написано 20 раз подряд? `"texttexttext..."` и так 20 раз.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться `StringBuilder`-ом и обычным циклом `for` от `0` до `19` (включительно):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string str = "text";
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    sb.Append(str);
}
string result = sb.ToString();
```

---

Есть [вариант покороче](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3754630/3432401) с использованием `Enumerable.Repeat` и `string.Concat`:

```
string result = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(str, 20));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string txt = "text";
for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
    txt += "text";
}
```

Comment: Я думаю поменять одну цифру в цикле не составит труда, да и автор вопроса привел пример. Я думаю тут понятно как поведет себя программа.

Comment: Исправил количество итераций.

Comment: В первый раз все работало как должно - ровно 20 итераций. Не пудрите мне мозги, пожалуйста.

Comment: Понял свою ошибку.

Comment: Нет, давайте без чата. Главное что вы поняли и исправили ошибку. Неактульные более комментарии, кстати, стоит удалить.